# How do I execute HTTPRequest with Binary Data?

Tags: http-functions, web

I'm playing with Salesforce in Mathematica trying to automate some PDF upload. I would like to know how can I execute the HTTPRequest as described by the curl below:

[image]

Here is the [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm) for Salesforce website with copyable text.

How I do insert data where the text says: "Binary data goes here"? What is this HTTPRequest structure?

Any clue?

Crosspost in Wolfram Community [link](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2148894).

Comment: The structure looks like “multipart/form-data” (see [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28080392) and [the corresponding RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7578)). You will want to figure out the formats you need first. As is, this is not a question about Mathematica (yet?).

Comment: Does it help: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97658/5478 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [More complete "MutipartData" POSTs using URLFetch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52338/more-complete-mutipartdata-posts-using-urlfetch)

Comment: @MarcoB, it seams the `HTTPRequest` has a new way to handle Multipart. Can be checked in [URLRead Doc](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/URLRead.html) in the Scope Area

Comment: @Kuba, almost there. See my comment to MarcoB. :)

Comment: related: [Curl analog with URLRead/Execute?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/224652/142)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Caveat: I do not have a SalesForce account and have not tried this code against the real site.  But it works against the testing site https://httpbin.org/anything.*

For this example we will create minimal PDF content to be uploaded as the main document:

```
$pdf = ExportString[Image[{{1}}], "PDF"];
```

The SalesForce API requires us to create metadata for that document, expressed as JSON:

```
$entityDocument =
  <| "Description" -> "Marketing brochure for Q1 2011"
   , "Keywords" -> "marketing,sales,update"
   , "FolderId" -> "005D0000001GiU7"
   , "Name" -> "Marketing Brochure Q1"
   , "Type" -> "pdf"
   |> //
 ExportString[#, "JSON"]&;
```

We will also need our own SalesForce site and API token:

```
$site = "yourinstance.salesforce.com";    (* or "httpbin.org/anything" *)
$apiToken = "InsertRealTokenHere";
```

Now we can assemble an HTTP request that includes the metadata and file as separate parts.  The form part named *entity_document* will specify the metadata whereas the part named *Body* will specify the document content.

```
$req = HTTPRequest[
  "https://"~~$site~~"/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/Document/"
  , <| "Method" -> "POST"
     , "Headers" -> <| "Authorization" -> "Bearer "~~$apiToken |>
     , "Body" -> <| "entity_document" ->
                     <| "MIMEType" -> "application/json"
                      , "Content" -> $entityDocument
                      |>
                  , "Body" ->
                      <| "Name" -> "2011Q1MktgBrochure.pdf" 
                       , "MIMEType" -> "application/pdf"
                       , "Content" -> $pdf
                       |>
                  |>
    |>
  ];
```

The `"Content"` property of a form part could also take a value of `ByteArray[...]` for arbitrary binary data or of `File[...]` to reference a file already stored on disk.

Finally, we can submit the request using `URLRead` and extract properties of interest from the response:

```
$resp = URLRead[$req];

$resp["Properties"]

(* {"Body","BodyByteArray","BodyBytes","CharacterEncoding","ContentType","Headers","StatusCode","StatusCodeDescription","Version"} *)

$resp["StatusCode"]

(* 200 *)

$resp["ContentType"]

(* application/json *)

$resp["Body"]

(*
  {
    "id" : "015D0000000N3ZZIA0",
    "errors" : [ ],
    "success" : true
  }
*)
```

Comment: That's very cool. I'll try it with my Salesforce credentials and comment the result here.